# Why is Angular Dart 2 ViewEncpasulation no longer accepting enums?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular

In Angular Dart 2 Alpha 35 the @view component accepted an enum value:

```
@View(
  styleUrls: const ["package:tickets/client/components/flight_display/flight_display.css"],
  templateUrl: "package:tickets/client/components/flight_display/flight_display.html",
  directives: const[CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.NONE
)
```

The   encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.NONE` now throws the following error:

```
Error:(11, 18) Arguments of a constant creation must be constant
 expressions
```

**Question:**
What is the proffered way to pass the value from an enum to the ViewEncapsulation object?

**Context**

Here is the Enum for the Angular.Dart 2 Lib:

```
enum ViewEncapsulation {
  /**
   * Emulate scoping of styles by preprocessing the style rules
   * and adding additional attributes to elements. This is the default.
   */
  Emulated,
  /**
   * Uses the native mechanism of the renderer. For the DOM this means creating a ShadowRoot.
   */
  Native,
  /**
   * Don't scope the template nor the styles.
   */
  None
}
```

Comment: If it's used in an annotation it has to be a constant and from its capitalization it looks like it is supposed to be a constant. I guess it is a bug in the ts2dart transpilation. Have you checked whether it is a const or not?

Comment: The enum is not a const. Added it to the OP

Comment: Enums are always const (I assumed an old-style enum). This looks like a Dart analyzer bug, have you tried to launch the app despite the warning? Might only be an analyzer problem but still work fine in VM/dart2js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `,` missing after `const[CORE_DIRECTIVES]` (found by https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4169#issuecomment-140011891) and ViewEncapsulation.NONE should be ViewEncapsulation.None

```
@View(
  styleUrls: const ["package:tickets/client/components/flight_display/flight_display.css"],
  templateUrl: "package:tickets/client/components/flight_display/flight_display.html",
  directives: const[CORE_DIRECTIVES],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
)
```